# Using "select for update" with jdbi3?

Tags: jdbi

Can someone please provide me a simple example of using "select for update" with jdbi3? I have looked all over internet and official documentation of jdbi3, and all I could find is `concurrentUpdatable`.

What about actually updating part?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

You would use it as usual. In 1 transaction, you would first execute `SELECT...FOR UPDATE`(@SqlQuery). After that in same transaction you could execute any update query(@SqlUpdate).

I wrote annotations for Object API, but it could be used with fluent API as well.

When you use `FOR UPDATE`, the table or row... more on this [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-select.html), is locked until the transaction is "released"(depending on version, there was some issues with rollback to)

Comment: Thanks for the info @Spasa

Comment: Thanks for this info :)